# What xaml code to get this layout?

Tags: silverlight, layout

In a specific parent control of my page, I want to layout horizontally some child controls (let's say rectangles) so that each control has the same width and has a maximum width.
This means that, given a large parent control:

- if there is only one child control, it won't span over the whole parent but will have its width set to the max width.
- After adding child controls, at a certain point, the sum of these max width (which the same for each child control btw) will be greater than the parent width. In this case, the total width should be divided by the number of children and each child will get this result.

Because the parent control must be bound to a collection, I began to write this:

```
<ItemsControl Margin="10" Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ChildShape />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I quickly realized that the StackPanel is not what I want.

The final goal is to have nice animations when a child is added or removed (other children must slide and change their size smoothly.

Since I'm new to Silverlight, I can't see what panel (custom or not?) I should use or how I can achieve what I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could experiment with a

```
 <UniformGrid Rows="1"> </UniformGrid>
```

To replace the StackPanel. If SilverLight has it, I'm talking from WPF.

Comment: Its not built into the SL framework, but a quick search online will find someones SL implementation. http://www.google.com/search?q=uniformgrid+silverlight

Comment: @foson: thx, seems the one from Jeff Wilcox could be a good start to write and customize a panel that will place my items the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for the UniformGrid idea.

For animations when items are added or removed, take a look at this post / MIX presentation.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2010/03/16/dynamic-layout-and-transitions-in-expression-blend-4.aspx

Comment: Since the Grid has no ItemsSource, how would I bind my collection to this structure?

Comment: Before you edited your message you were mentioning a simple Grid so I tried to replace the StackPanel above with a Grid. First, when adding children, they all go in the first cell. Second, I need to control the number of columns. It should be the same than the number of children.

Comment: Yeh, I didn't realize you wanted to replace the ItemsPanelTemplate at first.   Sorry for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could use the Wrap Panel.  [Jesse Liberty](http://jesseliberty.com/2009/01/02/silverlight-toolkit-wrappanel/) has a nice blog post explaining how to use it.

Comment: The children should not wrap but shrink.